# Getting error in IE console as "Extra "<body>" tag found. Only one "<body>" tag should exist per document."

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

We are using Bootstrap for implementing tabs in our application.

Putting Tabs using below markup

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills col-sm-12">
   <li>Tab logic</li>
 </ul>
```

Putting Tab content using below markup

```
<div class="tab-content col-sm-12">
</div>
```

Tab content is Div to show specific view. But When I check browser console, I see below error in console.

Kindly suggest help.

```
Browser Version IE11

Unexpected DOCTYPE. Only one DOCTYPE is allowed and it must occur before any elements.
Extra "<html>" tag found. Only one "<html>" tag should exist per document.
Extra "<body>" tag found. Only one "<body>" tag should exist per document.
```

Comment: Please show some actual code

Comment: Tabs
 <ul class="nav nav-pills col-sm-12">
            for (int i = 0; i < MyTabModel.Count; i++)
            {
                <li Html.Raw(i == 0 ? "class='active'" : string.Empty)><a data-toggle="tab" href="#some model</a></li>

Content

<div class="tab-content col-sm-12">

            for (int i = 0; i < Model; i++)
            {
                <div  Html.Raw("class=" + (i == 0 ? "'tab-pane fade active in col-sm-12'" : "'tab-pane fade col-sm-12'"))>
                   Model ,Model )
                </div>
            }
        </div>

            }
        </ul>

Comment: kindly ignore Razor syntax and Model structure

Comment: @AnkitChitransh edit your question. Don't post code in comments - it's unreadable

Comment: So do you have multiple html and body tags?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you probably have if IE statements in your HTML.

Following the [official documentation of IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx): *"Conditional comments are no longer supported"*.

Please provide your entire code on http://codepen.io/ to bring a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It was because

1. We were returning Model to landing View (by returning View as result)
2. Now from our landing view, we were calling @Html.Action (child actions).
3. For each of those child action, We were returning View as result instead of PartialView as result and hence were getting multiple Html Body tags.